# The multi-part identifier "Registry.categoryID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, join

I had to update a MSSQL db from 5 to 14, requiring a search query to be updated as well. I am new.

```
SELECT 
        Registry.registryID
        ,Registry.categoryID
        ,A.textImage
        ,Registry.categoryOrder
        ,B.InvName
        ,B.retail_price
        ,C.brideLastName
        ,C.brideFirstName
        ,C.groomLastName
        ,C.groomFirstName
        ,Registry.ProductID
        ,Registry.quantity
        ,Registry.quantityGot
        ,Registry.inventoryType
        ,Registry.nonInvDesc
        ,Registry.nonInvPrice
        ,Registry.nonInvDesc
        ,event.eventDate
        ,EventType.eventName
        ,event.eventID
        ,C.RegistrantID
        ,B.Desc_Short
        ,B.img_large
        ,b.Personalize_Flag
   FROM Registry,event
       LEFT JOIN registryCategory
       ON Registry.categoryID = A.regCategoryID
       LEFT JOIN products B
       ON Registry.ProductID = B.ProductID
       LEFT JOIN registrant C
       ON event.registrantID = C.RegistrantID
       INNER JOIN eventType
       ON event.eventid = #eventid#
       INNER JOIN EventType
       ON Event.eventTypeCode = EventType.eventTypeCode
    ORDER BY A.sortOrder,Registry.categoryOrder,Registry.registryID
```

Executing the code gives me - The multi-part identifier `Registry.categoryID` could not be bound.

Comment: you are mixing "old" and "new" join syntaxes!

Comment: As an aside, your query is vulnerable to sql injection. Always use bind variables (ie cfqueryparam if you are running the query via CF).